# Getting Same OpenApi response for all Apache CXF endpoints with OpenApiFeature

Tags: spring, cxf, openapi, swagger-2.0

I'm working on integrating OpenApi to my Apache CXF project [(github link with README)](https://github.com/shu-bham/openapi-cxf). I've referred this [doc](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/openapifeature.html) for this purpose.

Issues facing:

1. openapi.json for both the CXF endpoints are returning same json response
2. from the swagger-ui page when I try to invoke any of the endpoint request is going to invalid paths.
   Ex. For carSample endpoint, GET /car:
   Expected request URL : http://localhost:9090/api/carSample/car?page=1
   Actual request URL : http://localhost:9090/car?page=1

Can anyone let me know where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, my problem was the same and using the following customizer helps:

```
<bean id="swagger2Feature" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.openapi.OpenApiFeature">
   ...
    <property name="customizer">
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.openapi.OpenApiCustomizer">
            <property name="dynamicBasePath" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: Without this setup, swagger was unable to figure out what the right URL was to the rest endpoint due to the openapi server flags being wrong. This saved me a lot of work. Thanks!